# Remove a plus sign from positive numbers?

Tags: formatting, numbers, number-formatting

I have a list of numerical values, both negative and positive.

-1234.12
+5678.23

I want to remove the positive sign, but leave the negative sign on negative values.

-1234.12
5678.23

Is there an elegant way to do this?  I've found many examples on how to ADD a positive sign, but not remove one.

Comment: where have u stored numbers? in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using programming then use this (PHP)

```
$value = "-1234.12 +5678.23";
echo str_replace("+"," ",$value);
```

Comment: I was using Python, so this was the answer I was looking for.

    .replace("+", "")

Answer (score 0):

**the easiest**

if you are using Excel/Word, you can use Ctrl+F to call out the Find & Replace window to find/replace the wanted.

in this case, replace "+" to ""(nothing).

Or Ctrl + H in Notepad.